# String.getBytes() throws a Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, string, byte, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a file line by line and save it to a byte array, but for some reason String.getBytes() throws a Nullpointer Exception.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    byte[][] bytes = null;
    try {
        String data;
        int i = 0;
        while((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bytes[i] = data.getBytes(); // THROWS A NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION HERE
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(bytes.length);

    } catch (IOException e)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: `byte[][] bytes = null;` -- you never actually create an array.

Comment: YemSalat - are you using any IDE like eclipse ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, exactly right, and it did not throw the exception. It only showed up when I was trying to run the actual program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your byte array `bytes` is null. Why dont you use an `ArrayList`?

```
ArrayList<byte[]> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then later in your code:

```
bytes.add(data.getBytes());
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a better solution. Will I need to declare the type as well? Like so: `ArrayList<Byte>` ? [EDIT] You edited before I posted - thanks a lot, now its clear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the fact that `bytes` is `null` when you try to assign to it (you never instantiated it!). Try this instead:

```
byte[][] bytes = new bytes[N][];
```

You have to specify *at least* the number of rows in the `bytes` matrix *before* filling it. I don't know what's supposed to be the value of `N`, if it's unknown at the start of the loop then we can't use a `byte[][]` for storing the results - in that case, a variable-length data structure is required, for instance an `ArrayList<byte[]>` will do the trick:

```
String data;
List<byte[]> bytes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) { // we don't need `i` for anything
    bytes.add(data.getBytes());
}
System.out.println(bytes.size());        // this prints the number of rows
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you never initialized `bytes` to anyting but `null`:

```
 byte[][] bytes = null;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know the size of every array, plus the sizes might be different for each line read. Shall I use an ArrayList<byte> instead?

Comment: @YemSalat - Actually, I don't get any npe when i execute your code.

Comment: I don't get one in Eclipse, but I do when running in command line.